# ManyToMany Relation in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml

I have two entities: categories and products, One product can refer to a variety of categories. I made ManyToMany relationships in the Doctrine, and that's what I get (code I'll add below). There is a table with the items (id, name, price, etc.), a table with categories (id, name, child_id) and the table that links them (id_item, id_categories). I need to send the requester as a json array of type:

```
{
"name": "item1",
"price": 250,
"color": "red",
"size": 23
"weight": 45,
#And there point to which categories belong
}
```

So I do not understand how to implement this. If you do this separately, you can just shuffle the product id and category id into the linking table, and everything will work and display correctly, here is an example of a response (show all items):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bike",
    "price": 200,
    "color": "red",
    "size": 150,
    "weight": 15,
    "category": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "parent"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "child to 1",
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "parent"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Tell me, please, how can I do this? so that less trouble was ... Here are my Entities:
Item Entity:

```
class Item
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $color;
    private $size;
    private $weight;
    protected $category;
//getters and setters
}
```

Category Entity:

```
class Category
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $parent;
    private $children;
    protected $items;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 //getters and setters
}
```

Item.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Item:
    type: entity
    manyToMany:
        category:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            cascade: ['persist']
            inversedBy: items
            joinTable:
                name: item_category
                joinColumns:
                    item_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    category_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
    table: items
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        price:
            type: integer
        color:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        size:
            type: integer
        weight:
            type: integer
```

Category.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
        children:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            mappedBy: parent
            #orderBy:
                #name: ASC
  manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            inversedBy: children
            joinColumn:
                name: parentId
                referencedColumn: id
  manyToMany:
        items:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Item
            mappedBy: category
            cascade: ['persist']
  table: category
  repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
  id:
      id:
          column: id
          type: integer
          id: true
          generator:
          generator:
              strategy: AUTO
  fields:
      name:
          type: string
          lenght: 255
```

**Update:**
I learned that I need to make the variable $ category, to ArrayCollection, and create a new setter to add a category, then the Request array should be like this:

```
{   
    "name": "board",
    "price": 2,
    "color": "white",
    "size": 15,
    "weight": 1,
    "categories": 
        [
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 3}
        ]
}
```

But how to make a setter to record categories that are ArrayCollection?
My Controller:

```
public function postItemAction(Request $request)
{
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $content = $request->getContent();
    $item = $serializer->deserialize($content,'AppBundle\Entity\Item','json');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
    return new View($item,Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```